# UITableView change during delete

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableView cell that has a custom label inside to handle the variable height.  There is also an UIImage on the right and left.

When the table is toggled into edit mode, I want to inform and change each cell in the table, to format properly for being shifted to the right.  And, when the user presses the small -, I want to further optimize to make room for the delete button.

Looking for a pattern that works for the above, assuming there is custom content in the cell that I have control over.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using springs and struts in your storyboard or constraints?

Comment: springs and struts, we have to support 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Normaly all you need to do is set the springs and struts correctly and your content will slide correctly. If you create your sub-views in code then you need to make sure you call `addSubview` on the `cell.contentView` and not the `cell`.

To hide and / or resize the sub-views you need to override `willTransitionToState:`

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    UIView *imageView = self.rightImageView;
    UIView *labelView = self.centerTextLabel;

    CGRect labelFrame = labelView.frame;

    if (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {

        labelFrame.size.width += 52;

        // Animating the fade while the image is sliding to the left
        // is more jarring then just making it go away immediately
        imageView.alpha = 0.0;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            labelView.frame = labelFrame;
        }];

    } else if (!self.rightImageView.alpha) {

        labelFrame.size.width -= 52;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            imageView.alpha = 1.0;
            labelView.frame = labelFrame;
        }];
    }

    [super willTransitionToState:state];
}
```

I created a quick sample app up on GitHub that demos an iOS 4.3 app using a nib or code just uncomment `//#define USE_NIB_TABLEVIEWCELL` to use the nib

https://github.com/GayleDDS/TestTableCell.git

[image]

I personally prefer to create the table view cell in a nib file and only after profiling the App, replace the nib with code.